# I am not able to receive a response message when send a message in Discord?

Tags: python, discord, nextcord, ctx

I am not able to receive a response message when send a message in Discord? I think I have something wrong at here interaction.send("Hello!)

```
import nextcord
from nextcord import Button, Interaction
from nextcord.ext import commands
from config import DISCORD_ALERT_TOKEN

TESTING_GUILD_ID = 123456789 # Replace with your own guild IDs
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user.name} has connected to Discord.")
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(int(966316317890207779))
    await channel.send(f"{client.user.name} has connected to Discord.")

@client.slash_command(description="My first slash command", guild_ids=[TESTING_GUILD_ID])
async def hello(interaction: nextcord.Integration):
    await interaction.send("Hello!")  

client.run(DISCORD_ALERT_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

So after searching I found the problem.
[image: Scops to be set]

If the scope application command is unchecked it will not work.
You then have to select this and invite the bot again.

Comment: I got the on_ready feedback. I also used /hello command but this does not give me any response.

Comment: @GlobalSpotlight You have to select application commands in the discord developer portal and invite the bot again.

Comment: kick the bot and re-add it